# How to build PhoneGap apps with Cloud 9?

Tags: android, cordova, cloud9-ide

I have been playing around with PhoneGap, and as Cloud 9 is my IDE of choice, wondering if it's possible to use it, along with the PhoneGap native app for previews.

However, when i attempt the simple "Hello World" template, after `phonegap serve` i cannot access from the app in my phone, and the static IP on browser returns:

```
Cannot GET (Ip Address):3000?_c9_id=livepreview8&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this on your own server, or are you using the hosted workspaces from Cloud9? If the latter, then you need to connect to 0.0.0.0:8080 (or better $IP and $PORT). Those will be proxied to workspacename-username.c9.io.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
phonegap serve $PORT --nobrowser --nolivereload
```

Comment: `phonegap serve -p $PORT --no-autoreload` does it for me. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Hi for me worked doing:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create my-app
cd my-app
phonegap serve -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Holpe it helps